# Are joint distributions of roots independent in a PGM (Probabilistic Graphical Model)?

Tags: joint-distribution, independence, graphical-model

As stated in the question: Is the case in general that given the graph below the following relationship will hold?

P(A, C) = P(A) P(C)

[image]

I will edit later to ask this question in a general mathematical framework right now I do not have time to format.